# How do I remove a folder from a URL?

Tags: .htaccess

First of all, this question has been asked a few times on stack, however, none of the answers seem to work for me.

I have a website which has a "pages" folder in the root, I want to store all of my website pages in there.

Here's my structure

/pages/folder/folder2/index.php

I want to make it so the link displays:

https://wwww.website.com/folder/folder2/index.php

Removing the "/pages/" part of the URL, when I try all of the answers suggested previously, I get a 404 error.

Here is the htaccess I'm using

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^pages(/.*|)$ $1 [L,NC]  
</IfModule>
```

and i also tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^pages/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

This htaccess is in the root. I can't seem to get it working, can anyone offer any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: You might get better results researching over on serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

Your second attempt looks fine, though it can be imporoved a bit:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?pages/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301]
```

That rule should work inside the http servers host configuration or in some dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" style file) if the http server's rewriting module is loaded. You definitely should prefer the first option, but if you really need to use a dynamic configuration file then take care that the interpretation of such files is configured at all and that the file is placed in your hosts's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder and is readable for the http server process.

If that does not work then you need to start debugging. In this case you will start by monitoring your http server's error log file while making test requests. If no hint appears in there you need to enable rewrite logging which allows you to learn what exactly is going on inside the rewriting engine. See the official dpcumentation for the apache rewriting module for that. As typcial for OpenSource software it is of excellent quality and comes with great examples.